# ImageCaptureService.app what is it?

Tags: macos, cocoa, image-capture, evernote

`/System/Library/Services/ImageCaptureService.app` - what is it?

Evernote uses it for importing the images from scanners or cameras. How do the do that? I can't found any information about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Image Capture Services framework (part of Carbon.framework) is a high-level framework for capturing image data from scanners and digital cameras. The interfaces of the framework are device-independent, so you can use it to gather data from any devices connected to the system. You can get a list of devices, retrieve information about a specific device or image, and retrieve the image data itself. This framework works in conjunction with the Image Capture Devices framework (ICADevices.framework) to communicate with imaging hardware. For information on how to use the Image Capture Services framework, see [Image Capture Applications Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/ImageCaptureServicesProgrammingGuide/01Introduction/01Introduction.html).